How to write a Generic MudTab where it can render any component passing to it
I wanted to have Generic MudTab where  any component can  be passed in and it will render it.
<MudTabs Elevation="1" Rounded="true" PanelClass="pa-6">
    @ChildContent
</MudTabs>
@code
{
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}


How do I render the MudPanel ,  the requirement is the user should be able to  pass any component and it should render , How to handle how many panels are required for Mudtab?
For example say the MudTab has 3 panels  , the first panel is a grid component , The second panel  may be  a component with checkboxes , list boxes , radio button  and it may have multiple components rendering like razor1.razor and razor2.razor, and the last one  panel may be razor.razor component.

Your question is a bit short on detail, so I may have misunderstood your intent.
Here's a one page demo showing how to use DynamicComponent based on the MudBlazor Tab help page example.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Tab Demo</MudText>

<MudTabs Elevation="2" Rounded="true" ApplyEffectsToContainer="true" PanelClass="pa-6">
    @foreach (var tab in this.Tabs)
    {
        <MudTabPanel Text="@tab.Title">
            <DynamicComponent Type="tab.ControlType" Parameters="tab.Parameters" />
        </MudTabPanel>
    }
    </MudTabs>

    @code {
    public record MyTab
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } = "Tab";
        public Type? ControlType { get; init; }
        public Dictionary<string, object>? Parameters { get; init; }
    }

    public List<MyTab> Tabs = new()
    {
        new() {Title = "Counter", ControlType=typeof(Counter), Parameters = new(){ {"InitialCount", 50 } } },
        new() {Title = "Weather", ControlType=typeof(Weather)},
    };

}

I've updated Counter to demo passing parameters:
@page "/counter"
@page "/counter/{InitialCount:int}"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Counter</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-4">Current count: @currentCount</MudText>
<MudButton Color="Color.Primary" Variant="Variant.Filled" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</MudButton>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int InitialCount {get; set;}

    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentCount = this.InitialCount;
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}


